# I can't get a complete xls file, only the table header by python3 requests

Tags: python, excel, get, python-requests, xls

I want to export a report from a [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTfnp.png),when i clicked the export botton,it will download a xls file.

First,In the postman,i can get a compete report
[postman response result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSwuw.png)

this is response headers in postman

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
content-disposition: attachment;filename=U3sdad.xls
Content-Language: zh-CN
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2019 10:17:24 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But when i use resquests,I just get the table headers in the xls file.
I tried to use 2 way to get the xls

1:

```py
#I ues session,because i need cookie to login
s = requests.session()
report_response = s.get(url=report_url, params=params)
with open('1.xls','wb') as f:
    f.write(report_response.content)
```

2:

```py
#I ues session,because i need cookie to login
s = requests.session()
report_response = s.get(url=report_url, params=params,stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
with open('1.xls','wb') as f:
    for chunk in report_response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
        if chunk:
           f.write(chunk)
```

But they can't get a compete xls file like postman.
I don't know why,and i don't find a solution in Google

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import requests
dls = "http://url/path/to.xls"
resp = requests.get(dls)

output = open('test.xls', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

or this

```
import requests
dls = "http://url/path/to.xls"
resp = requests.get(dls)
with open('test.xls', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)
```

both should work.

Comment: Change my link to :'http://127.0.0.0:8089/jeecg/cgExportExcelController.do.xls   '?

Comment: I think you don't have space the end of URL.

Comment: Yes,there is not have space.I do it by url='127.0.0.0:8089/jeecg/cgExportExcelController.do.xls',but the test.xls can't open,and the file's size only 2KB,in the postman,the response's size is 4.9MB

Comment: ,i use notepad++ open text.xls,file content display 404